# Setting Buttons without using XML layout

Tags: android, eclipse

Im using eclipse to create my 1st game program. My question is. is it possible to setup a button without using xml?

having a problem on declaring 2 setcontentviews. the button is not actually appearing on the game. can somebody help me in this one?

```
public class Game extends Activity {
Maze maze;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    this.maze = (Maze)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if(this.maze == null) {
        this.maze = (Maze)extras.get("maze");
    }
    GameView view = new GameView(this);
    view.setMaze(this.maze);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Press me");
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

      RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

      myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);

        setContentView(myLayout);
    setContentView(view);
}       
}
```

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_User_Interface_in_Java_Code

Comment: No probs. If you have any more (specific) questions, just edit this question.

Comment: i have a problem on coding the buttons. please help

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button button = new Button(this) ;
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

  }) ;
```

OR

```
ViewGroup vg = new RelativeLayout(this) ;
  ImageView iv = new ImageView(this) ;
  vg.addView(iv); 
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) ;
  vg.setLayoutParams(params);
  setContentView(vg) ;
```

Hope this is what you are asking
As an alternative to using XML.

Answer (score 0):

yes button can be displayed without using xml and the following things to be done for this purpose

1. create Activity and overwrite oncreate method
2. make instance of button 
       Button button = new Button("Button by code");

   3.and set view by  setContentView(button);

Comment: is it possible to have 2 setcontentview?

Comment: yes 2 setcontentview can be used but the latest one is used
eg: 
setContentView(button1)
.................
................
setContentView(button2)
then button2 is displayed

And if you need both buttons 
then put both buttons in  linearlayout 
and then displays the linearlayout
setContentView(linearlayout)

Comment: i have a problem on coding the buttons. please help